# No module named 'cv2' even installed already in conda list

Tags: opencv

Traceback (`most recent call last`):

```
File "c:\Users\geode\MIA\MIA.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I have installed opencv2 in several ways, but it says it is not there.

I already removed all `opencv modules` and typed:

```
[conda install -c conda-forge opencv]
```

present conda list

```
numpy                     1.22.3          py310hed7ac4c_2   
opencv                    4.7.0           py310h5588dad_2    
py-opencv                 4.7.0           py310hbbfc1a7_2
```

Comment: Please post all textual info as copy-pasted text, not images/links.

Comment: thank you for your time, i'll post all textual after installation one more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may have something to do with the environment setup.  Did you install it in the base environment, or a new one? If in the base, make sure you run

```
conda activate base
```

it should say (base) before any information in the prompt, like this:

[image]

if you are not in the base environment, and you created a new one, you can see if it's installed by typing

```
conda list | grep opencv
```

and you should see it installed:

[image]

also you can confirm the executable being used by the environment with this

python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"

[image]

This shows your environment is set up properly. If you need more information about managing environments there [are good instructions here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html).

Comment: Thank you for your time!!

it really works , Hope everything is good.